# Parse Creating Table with Object: Doesn't display even though record exists

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When I try and create a table using Parse, It says User(3) meaning there are existing records in the table, however, it says "You don't have any data to display". Strangely, this only doesn't work if I try and create a "User" table. If I do "Users" "hello" or any other words, it works... Is this a bug?

I attached a picture below to show you what I mean, but if you click Users or any other table, it will display the data.

This person has had the same exact problem as I (Notice that he tried using "User" also):
https://www.parse.com/questions/message-you-dont-have-any-data-to-display-yet-but-records-exist

```
ParseObject user = new ParseObject("User");
user.put("username", username);
user.put("email", email);
user.put("password", hashedPassword);
user.put("last_session", last_session);
user.saveInBackground();
```

[image: Picture of non-working User]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"_User" class should be created only from code.

If you want to add values to _User table,

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("username", username);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("email", email);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("password", hashedPassword);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("last_session", last_session);
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Should I create it this way, or is "Users" better? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: I think , "_User" is to handle user details by the parse cloud  itself.So by using this ,we can easily access values from _User table by the above answer.